# Drop row if value date is not a max date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table looking similarly to the one below. I want to be able to drop row when current value date is not the max date in the table. In this case the row where current value is not null should be dropped because the date is not the max date.

| date | history | current |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6/1/2019 | 0 | NULL |
| 9/1/2019 | 0 | NULL |
| 12/1/2019 | 0 | NULL |
| 3/1/2020 | 0 | NULL |
| 6/1/2020 | 470.006 | NULL |
| 9/1/2020 | 248.028 | NULL |
| 12/1/2020 | 246.276 | NULL |
| 3/1/2021 | NULL | 273.7215714 |
| 4/1/2021 | 269.182 | NULL |
| 7/1/2021 | 297.919 | NULL |
| 10/1/2021 | 312.68 | NULL |
| 1/1/2022 | 300.932 | NULL |
| 4/1/2022 | 340.767 | NULL |

Comment: Dear Yana. As you can see on the answers it is a bit unclear what you want. Please show us how you expect the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
df = df[(df['current'].isnull()) | (df['date'] == df['date'].max())]
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't indicate if the date where current is not null is the max date. I need to know that and to drop this row if its date is not the max date

Comment: My new submit will keep a row if 'current' is NULL or 'date' is not equal to max

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If your DataFrame is called `df`, then you can keep only the max date values by using a mask:

```
df = df[df['date'] == df['date'].max()]
```

Here you are saying that you only want rows from `df` where the value in the column `df['date']` is equal to the max value from `df['date']`.

If you only want this where the 'current' column is not `NULL`, then you can do the following:

```
df = df[(df['current'] == 'NULL') | (df['date'] == df['date'].max())]
```

Comment: No, I want to drop the row where the current value is not null if this row's date is not the max date.

Comment: Yes, my second line of code will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you want to do, but here's my take.

Convert your dates to pandas datetime objects and replace `NULL` values with `NaN`.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = df.replace('NULL', np.nan)
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

Then you can do:

```py
df.query('not (~current.isna() and date != date.max())')
```

This drops the row with `current` value `273.7215714` since its date is not the maximum date. If you add another row with the maximum date (`2022-04-01`) and any non-null `current` value, it should be kept.

The resulting table looks like this (row 7 from original df dropped):

|  | date | history | current |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-06-01 00:00:00 | 0 | nan |
| 1 | 2019-09-01 00:00:00 | 0 | nan |
| 2 | 2019-12-01 00:00:00 | 0 | nan |
| 3 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | 0 | nan |
| 4 | 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | 470.006 | nan |
| 5 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00 | 248.028 | nan |
| 6 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 | 246.276 | nan |
| 8 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | 269.182 | nan |
| 9 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 297.919 | nan |
| 10 | 2021-10-01 00:00:00 | 312.68 | nan |
| 11 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 300.932 | nan |
| 12 | 2022-04-01 00:00:00 | 340.767 | nan |